# How to separate a list of strings it sees as a whole

Tags: linux, bash

I have 2 list of strings I generated and put in variables, `$t` and `$nnpp`. Then used the comm command to compare them.

```
pcr=$(comm -13 <(echo “$t” | sort) <(echo “$nnpp” | sort))
```

Then added the differences back into the main and sorted it.

```
psl=$(sort <(echo $t) <(echo $pcr) | uniq)
```

Now when I try to loop through that new list I made `$psl`, it is seen as one thing and grabs everything on the first iteration. How can I break it apart so I can loop through it?

I have already tried this but it didn’t work.

```
for e in “${psl[@]}”
then
     echo $e
done
```

I also have this at the beginning of my script if you are wondering.

```
IFS=$’\n’
IFS=$’\t’
```

Comment: Are you really using curly quotes in your code?  Also `psl` is not an array, it's just a variable.  Additionally you need to show us a sample of what you "list of strings" looks like

Comment: you'll probably find this a lot easier to do with temporary files than with process substitution.  and probably a lot faster, too - even if you were using an array, iterating through a loop with bash is a lot slower than giving a file argument to cat or sort or uniq etc.   and it's worth noting that if the data sets are small, the tmp files probably won't ever get flushed to disk before they're deleted; and if they're large, processing them in a bash variable will be a very slow memory hog.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem you're having is the lack of quotes in this line, which is making the contents of `$t` and `$pcr` into a single line, which makes `psl` simply have two long lines with many words in it.

```
psl=$(sort <(echo $t) <(echo $pcr) | uniq)
```

A simple first fix would be:

```
psl=$(sort <(echo "$t") <(echo "$pcr") | uniq)
```

But then you'll want to iterate `$psl` line by line (I'm assuming you're processing it linewise, since you're using tools like `sort`, `uniq` and `comm`.)

```
while read -r e ; do
    echo "$e"
done <<<"$psl"
```

This actually gets much easier if you use temporary files instead:

```
echo "$t" | sort >t.sorted
echo "$nnpp" | sort >nnpp.sorted
comm -13 t.sorted nnpp.sorted >pcr
sort t.sorted pcr | uniq >psl
while read -r e ; do
    echo "$e"
done <psl
```

BTW, since `pcr` simply has the lines unique in `nnpp` and you're using `uniq` which should get rid of duplicates between `t` and `nnpp`, perhaps you can get away with the much simpler:

```
echo "$t" >t
echo "$nnpp" >nnpp
sort -u -o psl t nnpp
```

Note that `sort`'s `-u` flag is the same as piping through `uniq`, and that you can pass `sort` a `-o` flag to name the file where to write the sorted output.